Definition inside remark, the title is affected and became italic instead of bold
The problem is: When I use definition in remark, the definition title which should be bold becomes italic. If I use remark in definition, everything is fine. The code is like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
test
\begin{definition}
test
\end{definition}
\end{remark}

\begin{definition}
test
\begin{remark}
test
\end{remark}
\end{definition}

\end{document}

The result is like:

Like, why does this even happen? And how to solve it?

amsthm doesn't expect nesting of theorem-like environments.

amsthm doesn't expect nesting of theorem-like environments.
You can cure the specific problem by adding some code when definition starts up.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{definition}{\thm@headfont={\normalfont\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
test
\begin{definition}
test
\end{definition}
\end{remark}

\begin{definition}
test
\begin{remark}
test
\end{remark}
\end{definition}

\end{document}


However, I'd first of all discourage such nesting that makes little sense. If you insist, you should define your own styles.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{zhendefinition}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\upshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\normalfont\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\newtheoremstyle{zhenremark}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\upshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\normalfont\itshape} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{zhenremark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{zhendefinition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
test
\begin{definition}
test
\end{definition}
\end{remark}

\begin{definition}
test
\begin{remark}
test
\end{remark}
\end{definition}

\end{document}

